# Is there any tools for observing magnetic fields and forces of black holes and galaxies?

Tags: magnetic-fields, astrophysics, astronomy

I want to know about how we can find magnetic forces and fields in space around stars, planets, galaxies, pulsars especially pulsars. How (by what means) did determine magnetic fields around a pulsar?

Comment: Probably radio synchrotron

Comment: These fields are only detectable with either matter as a local probe or, if they are time varying, by their electromagnetic emissions. In the first case we a performing some kind of spectroscopy, from the microwave region all the way to the x-ray spectrum. The field of a magnetar is somewhere on the order of 10^10T, I believe, so the spin precession of electrons should be somewhere in the soft-x-ray region. Proton precession might be in the optical if I am not mistaken, but I am not sure it's observable.

Comment: @FlatterMann I don't think anybody has seen electron precession in magnetars, but we've seen electron cyclotron resonances in less magnetized neutron stars, e.g. https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1979Natur.282..240W/abstract

Comment: @JohnDoty Thanks for the link. I am not into astronomy enough to be well informed. I did NMR as a student, so I am kind of fond of the idea of doing it in some really high fields. The signal strength scales (at least in the weak field) with the power of 2/3, so one would gain 15 orders of magnitude in 1e10T conditions... that's not small potatoes.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by studying the polarization of light that has passed through a strong magnetic field. In some circumstances the field will rotate the direction of the polarization of a light beam (the so-called *faraday effect*). This has been used to infer the presence of very large-scale magnetic fields surrounding, for example, distant galaxies.